# How to remove warnings caused by Firebase in .mm file

Tags: ios, firebase, objective-c++

I get many warnings when I add Firebase Crash into my iOS project.

Because I need call some C++ methods in my AppDelegate file, I change the AppDelegate.m for AppDelegate.mm file.  After I import the Firebase header file and build the project, there will be many warnings (Documentation Issue Group) like:

> /myproject/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/Headers/FIREventNames.h:138:6: HTML tag 'ul' requires an end tag

If I change it back to `AppDelegate.m`, the warnings will disappear.
So does anyone have an idea about that? How can I use a `.mm` file without such warnings?

Many thanks!

Comment: What version of Firebase Analytics do you use?

Comment: Hi @RomanPodymov, I'm not sure what version it was when the problem happened. I "fixed" the warnings by commenting the code in <ul> block and then update to latest version. Now the warnings seems disappeared.

Comment: Did you used a special version of this library for C++?

Comment: Oh no, just standard library